# List selector with different image on the right

Tags: android, listview, selector

I want to have a marker on the right side of a list item that changes if the list item is checked or not. I put in the layout of the list item an ImageView that has a selector background drawable :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selector_marked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selector"/>

</selector>
```

I have created a CheckableFrameLayout class that is the root of the list_item layout that implements checkable.

This is my ImageView on the right side of the list item:

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selector"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector_land" />
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks